# Parse returns empty 400 to POST request

Tags: rest, post, parse-platform, http-post

Every time I send a pretty minimal request to Parse API:

```
POST /1/some_url HTTP/1.1
X-Parse-Application-Id: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
X-Parse-REST-API-Key: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
Content-Type: application/json

{"data":"value"}
```

I get the same empty response:

```
HTTP/1.1 400 BAD_REQUEST
Content-Length: 0
Connection: Close
```

And ideas about possible errors on my part?

Comment: parse.com says a 4xx error always has a JSON body describing the error. I'd speculate that you have an authentication error and they don't give the specifics for security reasons.

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question. In my case an additional header was needed:

```
Host: api.parse.com
```